# Creating a second close button within the lightbox

Tags: featherlight.js

I'm coming from 0 coding background knowledge, so I apologize in advance. I have been playing around with featherlight and have gotten my light box to open and display information. I added a button inside that when clicked, will send me to a different section of my index page. How can I make the light box close from clicking my linked button after it sends me to the linked page?
Thanks!

```
<div class="sqs-block button-block sqs-block-button">
    <a href="#" data-featherlight="#new-page" class="sqs-block-button-element--small sqs-block-button-element">Learn More</a>
</div>

<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="new-page">
        <p> <p>
        <h3>
        Class 101
        </h3> COMING SOON: TBD - NOT YET OPEN
        <ul>
            <li>Information</li>
        </ul>
        <br /> 
        <div class="sqs-block button-block sqs-block-button">
            <a href="#schedule" class="sqs-block-button-element--small sqs-block-button-element">Register</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Snel23, thanks for the clarification!